# Windows Developer - Uploading the signable file

Tags: windows, uwp, certificate, store

We're trying to uploading the signable file in order to upload our windows app, in the Windows Developer Dashboard :

https://ibb.co/knRYZG

We created a certificate with the **New-SelfSignedCertificate**, and used **SignTools** to sign the **SignableFile.bin**. This part is okay but when we upload the file, we get this error :

> Error: The code signing certificate authority (CA) you used isn’t on
>   the approved list of root certificates. Please get a certificate from
>   one of the CAs listed on the certificate info page.

Do you, please, have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of apps you want to publish through dashboard? It seems we don't need to upload the certificate file if we want to publish UWP apps. BTW, where do you get the page of your screenshot? I'm not able to find the page asking for the `.bin` file in Windows Dev Center.

Comment: If you're trying to publish a UWP app, make sure you select the "Windows & Xbox" program and not the "Windows Desktop Applications" program. The latter brings you to the page you're describing, which looks like it's for distributing desktop applications outside the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1):

They're telling you, essentially, that they want you to go out and buy a signing certificate from Symantec, Globalsign, or someone else they approve of or have licensing agreements of some sort with. Self signing / test signing is fine for internal testing, but for this they want you to show that you're a bit serious and part of a company or organization. (In reality it feels a lot like a shake down though ;) )